# Builing DLL and getting error PRJ0019 and warnings LNK4222

Tags: visual-c++, dll

In my DLL defs file I had:

```
    EXPORTS
    DllCanUnloadNow     @1 PRIVATE
    DllGetClassObject   @2 PRIVATE
    DllRegisterServer   @3 PRIVATE
    DllUnregisterServer @4 PRIVATE
```

If I build it, I get 4 warnings LNK4222, exported symbol 'DllCanUnloadNow' should not be assigned an ordinal, I get this for each entry.

So I commented out each link with ;

Now when I build I get:

```
    error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing registration"
```

What is the correct way to resolve both issues?

Comment: Just remove `@1`, `@2` ... as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e705t74.aspx

Comment: Thank you, although the actual fix was just to remove the @# leaving in the PRIVATE as without it another warning is produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Alex P, the actual fix was to replace with:

```
EXPORTS
DllCanUnloadNow     PRIVATE
DllGetClassObject   PRIVATE
DllRegisterServer   PRIVATE
DllUnregisterServer PRIVATE
```